# SignalR hub closes connection after method invoked

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-3.1, signalr-hub

I using a net core 3.1 app with a very basic Hub. Everything works as expected locally. But on server the websocket connection is closed after first call is executed.

I am sure that websockets are enabled on the server. Another part using Blazor Server works fine. And also as long as no hub method is called the websocket connection is alive.

Also the client receives the data send by the hub.

Testing in chrome, after clicking the button, alert box shows the three messages. Then the connection is lost:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed.

I already tested to connect to server with client from local machine, which does not work. So it shouldn't be a client issue here.

Working with local client and local running app, everything works fine.

TestHub.cs

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task Test(string name)
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Message", $"Hello, World! ({ name }) 1");
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Message", $"Hello, World! ({ name }) 2");
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Message", $"Hello, World! ({ name }) 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Index.html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.7/signalr.min.js"></script>

<h1>Test</h1>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>

<script>
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/Hub/Test")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

    function start() {
        try {
            connection.start();
            console.log("SignalR Connected.");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setTimeout(start, 5000);
        }
    };

    connection.on("Message", (message) => {
        alert(message);
    });

    function test() {
        try {
            connection.invoke("Test", "Foo");
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }

    start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the nuget Mongo2Go caused the problems. With version 3.1.3 they added System.Text.Json 5.0.1 which breaks signalr.

Downgrading Mongo2Go to version 3.1.1 made signalr working again.